# html data-error shown based on javascript result

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a password field. If its not 6 characters long, a error is thrown.
I want more customised checking. After the value is entered. I want a  `checkMyKad()` javascript function triggered.

Function checkMyKad() does lot of complex manual checking on the field. if all correct it returns true, other false. If false then only I want data-error to be displayed.

How do we do that?

```js
var patt = /^[0-9]{6}\-?[0-9]{2}\-?[0-9]{4}$/;

function hasValidHypens(dateStr) {
  if (dateStr.indexOf("-") > 0 && dateStr.split("-").length != 3) return false;
  else return true;
}

function isValidDate(dateStr) {
  var month = parseInt(dateStr.substring(2, 4));
  var date = parseInt(dateStr.substring(4, 6));
  return month != 0 && month <= 12 && date != 0 && date <= 31;
}

function hasValidRegion(dateStr) {
  var badRegions = [17, 18, 19, 20, 69, 70, 72, 73, 80, 81, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 00];
  var reg = 0;
  if (dateStr.indexOf("-") > 0) {
    reg = parseInt(dateStr.split("-")[1]);
  } else {
    reg = parseInt(dateStr.substring(6, 7));
  }
  return !(jQuery.inArray(reg, badRegions) >= 0);
}

function validate(ic) {
  return patt.test(ic) && hasValidHypens(ic) && isValidDate(ic) && hasValidRegion(ic);
}

function checkMyKad() {
  var mykadC = $('registerpassword').val();
  return validate(mykadC);                
}
```

```html
<form data-toggle="validator" method="post" role="form" novalidate="true">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control block-centered login-input" 
    data-error="Password need to be 6 characters minimum" data-minlength="6" 
    id="registerpassword" placeholder="Password" required="" type="text">
    <div class="help-block with-errors txt-centered"></div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Show us your JavaScript code as well...

Comment: Is it related to Java? JavaScript and Java is pretty different, you know?

Comment: I have added my javascript function. it can return true or false